# How to sign in to Google then get the output html?

Tags: python, google-signin, burp

How do I sign in to Google then get the output html, with a Python Script?

I don't want to use Selenium, just a sequence of GET/POST requests.

I have used Burp Suite to intercept the POST request when I entered my email. I don`t understand all those parameters and fields and get a 405 error.

I have tried:

```
import requests
URL = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/identifier?flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession"

r = requests.post(url = URL, data ={'f.req':'my_email'})

output = r.text
```

Post Headers
[image: Post Headers]

Post Params
[image: Post Params]

I need to do a POST Request to sign in and after that a GET Request to get the next page.

Comment: You're going to want to use a `Session` object to keep the cookies, you can also inspect the post in your browser to see what other params are passed

Comment: The Burp Suite shows me the params that are passed. I must input all of them manually in python? ( URL, Cookies, Body) and i must also put the headers?

Comment: lots of the header will be manual, the session object should handle the cookies, but the body will depend. Some of it will be manual, but some of it could be values in the html in the login page. If these are generated with JS, you may have to use selenium

Comment: Ok thanks i will give it a shot

Comment: Guys an update i have found out that in a post request to sign in to Google there  is value "reqid" which every time is different

Comment: Does this value affect authentication? Should i insert it in my POST request and if yes how can i generate it?

Comment: Yea you should probably insert it. usually these types of things are "hidden" in the html. If you inspect the elements and search for "reqid", you may find it. You could use beautifulsoup to get that value each time you want to sign in.

Answer (score 0):

This is the python script to login to your gmail account

```
import requests

url = "https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier"

querystring = {"service":"mail","passive":"true","rm":"false","continue":"https://mail.google.com/mail/","ss":"1","scc":"1","ltmpl":"default","ltmplcache":"2","emr":"1","osid":"1","flowName":"GlifWebSignIn","flowEntry":"ServiceLogin"}

headers = {
    'authorization': "Basic **base64 format of your email and password**",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "0a86044e-5956-9b9c-616b-6d9f22f1560c"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

Enter email and password in base64 decoded format, for example 
use this format

```
abc@xyz.com:pass@123
```

Comment: Thanks mate for your answer but because i am trying to identify if some email has One button Authentication google needs cookies so this can only be done either by session or headless browser like casperjs or selenium... I have tried to do it with session but i cant trick the server to give me the proper response i want due to cookies i think... I will try your answer though...

Comment: You can try `Postman`. Because I got this script using Postman. You can download it from [here](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) and upvote if it works :)